# Prove that the utility graph is nonplanar

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

I am currently studying Chapter 3 in **Introduction to Graph Theory** by Richard J. Trudeau. In this chapter, the author proves the utility graph is nonplanar by using the Jordan Curve Theorem and the corollary:

> If $C$ is a continuous simple closed curve in a plane and two points of $C$ are joined by a continuous curve $L$ in the plane having no other points in common with C , then except for its endpoints $L$ is entirely contained in one of the two regions determined by $C$.

The author first redraws the utility graph to look like a hexagon and then argues based on two cases (justified via the corollary): one where there are **two curves inside the hexagon** and **one outside**, and the other being **two curves outside the hexagon** and **one inside**.

The author then applies the Jordan Curve Theorem to both cases to argue that a crossing cannot be avoided.

This proof makes sense to me, but prior to looking at the solution, I attempted it myself, and I want to understand why the additional work is needed to prove $UG$ is nonplanar.

Here is the scratch work: [image]

It might be confusing since I didn't arrange it based on the hexagon structure. Is my flaw that I am only catching one case, and the way I drew the graph made it unintuitive to see the other case as captured in the author's proof? Any other errors or missteps? I didn't use the corollary - perhaps because I didn't break it into the cases.

Comment: As I understand your proof also holds for the graph that is obtained by removing vertex $Z$. Doesn't it?

Comment: X lies on C1 so does not exclusively lie in one region or the other. L could easily be drawn over the top of A without intersecting C1.